# SSRS Report Builder 3.0 MDX Time/Date Parameter Default Value

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I have been struggling with this all week and have yet to find an answer.  I have a fairly simple report with an Analysis Services Cube as the Data Source.

I am attempting to set the TimeDate parameter's default value to the previous date.  I am familiar with how to do this normally, but am having difficulty with MDX.

The following expressions does work, but pulls 1/8/2011 as the Cube's data value are based on the number of days since 1/1/2011 (e.g. the value '1136' generates 2/9/2014).

```
="[Time Date].[Date].&["+DAY(CSTR(DAY(NOW())+"]"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
="[Time Date].[Date].&[" + DateDiff(DAY, Date(2011, 1, 1), Today()) + "]"
```

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337092.aspx for the date functions of Reporting Services.

Comment: I am receiving a BC30455 error.  Argument not specified for parameter 'DateValue' of Public Fu8nction Day(DateValue as Date) as Integer.

Comment: OK, it seems there is an error in the documentation. You can try to either `"[Time Date].[Date].&[" + DateDiff("DAY", Date(2011, 1, 1), Today()) + "]"` or `"[Time Date].[Date].&[" + DateDiff(DateInterval.DAY, Date(2011, 1, 1), Today()) + "]"`. Sorry, I currently have no Reporting Services installation to try.

Comment: I am receiving a BC30108 error for both of those.  "Date is a type and cannot be used as an expression."